# each_with_index not working correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

i want the first element of the each loop to be "active" and wrap it with a active css class. I tried this, but every item is active now. What a i doing wrong?

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide
  .carousel-inner
    - @cities.each do |city|
      - city.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true).each do |b|
        - b.attachments.each_with_index do |a, index|
          - if index=0 
            .active.item
              = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px"))
              .carousel-caption
               %h4 yep 1
          - else 
            .item
              = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px"))
              .carousel-caption
                %h4 yep 2
```

Thanks..remco

Comment: Hi Remco, i think it's the if condition. Could you try to use `if index == 0` ?

Comment: kaeros..thanks i fixed it...but stil every item is "active"

Comment: Consider refactoring if the only change is a single class name, and consider a partial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be `if index == 0` not `if index = 0`

Anyway if I want to do what you are doing I would do the following

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide
  .carousel-inner
    - @cities.each do |city|
      - city.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true).each do |b|
        - b.attachments.each_with_index do |a, index|
          %div{ :class => "#{index == 0? 'active item' : 'item'}" }
            = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px"))
            .carousel-caption
              %h4
                = index == 0 ? 'yep 1' : 'yep 2'
```

Comment: try to print the index like `= index` and see the printed values

Comment: I think @Khaled didn't mean one more `.active.item` under `%div{...}` and it's a typo. I think if you remove that line with `.active.item`, then his example should work.

Comment: i tried this...

- @cities.each do |city|
                          - city.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true).each do |b|
                            - b.attachments.each_with_index do |a, index|
                              %div{ :class => "#{index == 0 ? 'active item' : 'item'}" }
                                = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px"))
                                .carousel-caption
                                  %h4
                                    = index == 0 ? 'yep 1' : 'yep 2'
but all items are stil active...

Comment: i printed the values with = index and everything is 0,0,0!

Comment: instead of 

`%div{ :class => "#{index == 0? 'active item' : 'item'}" }`


i would use
`%div.item{ :class => index == 0 ? 'active item' : nil }`